# Is it safe and legal to make this gas plumbing connection?

Tags: plumbing, safety, dryer, natural-gas

I have learned that, contrary to what they tell you, the big box stores will not connect your gas dryer when they deliver it.  So I was left to do it myself.

The guy told me to remove the incorrect sized inlet flange fitting on the wall pipe and replace it with a coupler.  The one I bought did not fit on one side.

But the flange that came with dryer fit the bare pipe threads so I installed it, used some goop, leaked tested with soapy water and ran the dryer and it works.  I circled my work in purple.

But is this the correct way to install a gas fitting???

EDIT2:
The inside of the steel fitting and the outside of the cast iron pipe are both threaded.

EDIT:
[image: ANOTHER VIEW]

[image: what I did]

[image: goop]

[image: What i bought that doesn't fit the wall pipe]

Comment: Some questions:  1) Do you have a tight seal? (confirmed with soapy water test)  2) Does gas flow to the dryer?

Comment: If there are no threads on the inside of that fitting, and the fitting is only attached with thread sealant, there is no mechanical connection, that is a violation.

Comment: They also sold you a coupling when they should've sold you (nothing) a half-inch to three-quarter adapter.  It's fine tho, that's why there's threads on the ID.

Comment: @The Evil Greebo  1) I think so.  Any more turns and I might strip the pipe.  I see no biubbles.  2) The dryer works

Comment: @Dan D.  Thanks Dan.  The inlet pipe and the steel coupler both have threads and it is wrenched on

Comment: @Mazura  Yes.  I couldn't bring all the fittings to the store so I had to make educated guesses as to sixe based on the one part i could take to the store

Answer (score 1):

Your flex tube looks like it has a flare fitting with light colored pipe dope. Flare fittings are metal to metal seal and dope interferes with the seal. Even if it does not leak now it can leak in the future. I investigated a house fire -death caused by this situation. Only a problem if you have a flare connection with pipe dope.

Answer (score 0):

Is it legal it depends on your location. Every state I have lived in a home owner can do there own plumbing and electrical. I believe you did the job correctly but normally don't use the inside outside fittings but purchase the correct black pipe adapter. You have a valve and used listed parts including gas rated pipe dope and last the leak test so as long as it is legal in your state I believe you are OK.